# What is the reading order of the Project Superpower comics

Tags: comics, suggested-order

I have previously purchased [The Boys verses Project Superpowers Humble Bundle.](https://www.humblebundle.com/books/boys-versus-project-superpowers-encore-books)

This included all *The Boys* comics and what I had believed to be all the *Project Superpowers* comics.

As I'm getting ready to read the *Project Superpower* comics I can see that there is both a main series as well as a series of spin offs.

I presume that the main series should be read first, but then I'm unsure of the reading order of the spinoffs or if all the spins offs are actually included. I believe that the following volumes are missing:

- Blackcross
- Scarlet Sisters
- Cat-man and Kitten
- Rocketman & Rocketgirl
- 1 volume of The Death-Defying 'Devil

The Humble Bundle included the following volumes:

- Project Superpowers, Vol. 1
- Project Superpowers Chapter 2 Vol 1
- Project Superpowers Chapter 2 Vol. 2
- The Black Terror Vol. 1
- The Black Terror Vol. 2
- The Black Terror Vol. 3
- The Owl
- Project Superpowers X-Mas Carol
- Masquerade
- Meet the Bad Guys
- The Death-Defying 'Devil (Vol. 2) #1

Comment: A significant proportion of these have been released in compilation volumes. Presumably reading these in the order #1, #2, #3 will take care of most of the comics. https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07JJKTBL4?binding=kindle_edition&ref=dbs_dp_rwt_sb_pc_tukn

Comment: I have the specific volumes as released as part of the humble bundle, so any other compilation volume won't have any relevance to the question

Comment: They seem highly relevant. And far more so than an assortment of comics released by a third party vendor.